# get only posts in the loop which ids are saved in other custom posts meta data

Tags: wordpress

I have two post types named `problem` and `solution`. 
Each solution has problemId saved as metadata and there can be multiple solutions to the same problem from different users. I'm looping those problems and want to exculde these which have solutions so I need to exclude these posts which Ids are saved in problems posts.

I have been using this code to loop the problems.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 9,
    'post_type' =>  'car_owner',
    'orderby'       =>  'post_date',
    'order'         =>  'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged,
); 
$loop = new WP_Query(build_query( $args ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store an array of solution IDs in the metadata of each problem. When a problem is created it starts with an empty array, let's call it *$nr_solutions*. Each time a solution is created its ID is added to *$nr_solutions*. To display problems without solutions create a loop that displays a problem only if *$nr_solutions* has a count of 0.